# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ header thingy usability question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, usability, stack-exchange-button

I ran into a small usability problem with the StackExchange link on the left side of the header bar.  I liked that I could quickly see responses from various SE sites.  But it wasn't immediately obvious how to *close it*.  There was no "X" in the upper-right corner and simply clicking on an open space in the window didn't make it go away.  I'll be honest, the lower-right corner was the **last** place I would expect to see a close link.  Is this a new trend in web UI that I'm not used to yet?

I'm asking primarily to spark discussion of how it can be improved.  If I was confused (and I'm a regular SE user), I'll bet others would be too.

Here is what I (jjnguy) see.

[image: Where Do I click?]

Comment: I was getting ready to post this same thing but a conference call got in the way.  For the record, the proper name is the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/203659#203659)

Comment: @rchern We need to go on an editing spree and add that to every meta post that mentions it

Comment: Clicking outside to close it is what I keep trying to do, but I know people don't like that.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32548/click-outside-the-box-to-dismiss-instead-of-having-to-click-inside

Comment: I hated not having the X in the corner also.

Comment: Me three - I used to reload the page to make it go away, it was only here that others have pointed out to me the "close" button in right bottom corner. Definitely didn't notice it there.

Comment: @Michael, I don't have edit privs here.

Comment: @Michael, nobody will search for "MultiCollider SuperDropdown" if they don't know the name.  That's why I haven't yet edited the title of this question.

Comment: @rchern Done :)

Comment: @Kriso Yeah, I was joking :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again given the title change.

Comment: <antique_joke> MultiCollider? But I just met her. </antique_joke>

Comment: **header thingy** should really be removed from the title though... ;)

Comment: Kristo, If my screenshot doesn't accurately depict what you are seeing, please remove it.

Comment: @jinguy, that looks like what I see.  Thanks for including a freehand circle with the picture.

Comment: @Kristo, glad to help.

Comment: Related, or duplicate if this turns into a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65669/location-of-the-close-button-on-the-stackexchange-popup-menu

Comment: Lol, My Time (referring to your browser tabs).

Comment: Try asking [ui.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com) if you're interested in serious suggestions.

Comment: @Patrick IIRC, UI.SE is for *others* UI, not SO's itself. It would simply be closed over there

Comment: @TheLQ It won't get closed. Trust me. :-) There's [at least one precedent](http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/1539) and it got 6 up votes. The SO platform often comes up in answers as well.

Comment: Agreed please make the clicktoclose function!!!

Comment: Oh, thank god - I thought I was the only one. I continually try to click outside the box to close it.

Comment: `[status-complete]` (sorta) - Clicking out closes the box, which does help. There is no X though

Comment: +1 - My wife says you are correct, the close button shouldn't be on the bottom, and a second click on the "Stack Exchange" title should close the popup, not go to another site.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As well as moving the close button, a click outside of the box should close the window as well. This is to be inline with most other sites (and certain parts of SO) that close popups by just clicking out of the window.

Comment: Yes, please - I don't know why, but I try clicking outside the box every single time I open it up. I never notice the tiny "close" link, so I guess I try and treat it like one of those lightbox picture popups.

Comment: Actually, clicking on the page behind seems to work on most of the SE sites... in fact, the only page I can consistently get it to NOT work on is MSO

Comment: And now it's working on all of the sites. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 24):

How about making it a little bit bigger?

[image]

140px should be enough for any one.

A little more seriously though, moving it to the top seems to me like a worse option, since the space up there is incredibly tight. Instead, may I suggest making the entire bottom area (which current doesn't contain anything anyway) the target area for the close link, as well as giving it a different shade of gray to easily distinguish the close link.

[image]

Comment: +1 because every user can immediately implement this solution himself simply by using [this cream](http://www.makemylogobiggercream.com/).

Comment: *excellent* idea.. for a two letter first name person, anyway :)

Comment: You can click anywhere in the footer to close the widget now (after tonight's push).

Comment: @Jeff If you make that joke one more time I'll come over to your house and smash your head open with a giant "Yi"

Comment: violence is never the answer. but sometimes an additional letter is.

Answer (score 14):

My instinct tells me that when I click again in the same place where I clicked to open it, then it should be closed. Taking me to [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) page really annoys me.

So I sugest moving [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) link to the bottom, and make top bar a "close link".

[image]

Comment: This is the one and only correct answer. If you make it look like a pull-down menu, make it behave like one too. The text "click again to close" isn't even necessary: simply changing the downward arrow to an upward one would work just as well.

Comment: Dammit - i want to click the questions in that screenshot

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the quickest way is to press <kbd>esc</kbd>.

But I happen to agree that it isn't *hugely* obvious at the moment (via either route).

Comment: Keyboard shortcut!  YES!!!

Comment: Oh, I guess that's rather obvious. I can't get in the habit of trying standard desktop keybindings on web apps

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that it's straying away from the time-tested control it evolved from. People know how to use drop-down/combo-boxes... they've been using them for years. Don't try to invent a brand new control.

How about making it behave more like a real drop-down box, where whatever pops up out of it doesn't obstruct the original control you clicked on. This way you don't need "close this" type links (which aren't very appealing), and the user will automatically know that they can click the drop-down box again to close the list.

Answer (score 1):

Huh. My first impulse was to just click the Stack Exchange logo again, and it worked.

<sub>Well, okay, it was only my first impulse because I'd already read this question. But it would have been my *second* impulse anyway.</sub>

EDIT: Proof in pictures:
[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: The StackExchange link (with the dropdown open) takes me to http://stackexchange.com.  Do you have an updated UI as a moderator?

Comment: I mean the one that you clicked on to open the dropdown, not the "Stack Exchange is a network..." bit. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Knowing that you run IE7, I think this might be browser specific - I used to do this when the dropdown first came out. But at least nowadays when I click it, the dropdown actually obscures the logo, so you can no longer click on it.

Comment: Come to think of it, it seems to me that the dropdown used to appear *below* the logo, whereas now it's to the side.

Comment: @mmyers, with Firefox 3.6.8 I click the little down arrow to bring up the box.  The arrow isn't visible after the window is open.  Ironically, I was going to make a joke about not including a picture with freehand circles but now it seems I may need one.

Comment: The thing you click to open the dropdown turns into the "Stack Exchange is a network..." With 'Stack Excange' being a link to stackexchange.com.

Comment: OK, pictures added. @Kristo

Comment: Woah, that's not what I see.

Comment: Yeah, this looks to be browser specific. In my native IE8, and when running on FF at home, the dropdown will obscure the logo. But if I switch to compatibility mode, it will appear to the side just as you depict in your images.

Comment: @mmy, see the edited question to see what we see.