# SE Network Dialog close button: more visual

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, vote-to-close

Could we make the close button more visual? It's not intuitively placed with normal conventions of where a close button would be, and it blends in too well.

Alternately, could we have it dismiss when off-clicking?

Comment: Related (and the last part is a dupe): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65838/147763