# Close the StackExchange drop down when it's out of focus

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I propose that once you click outside of the StackExchange network/inbox area, that it closes.

I realize that there is a close button but every time I've used dropdowns of this type, they fade out upon clicking some other area of the page.

Comment: Related: General usability of the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-header-thingy-usability-question) and its lack of ease of closing.

Comment: @Grace oh wow, I didn't even see that after a search or in the question suggestions.

Comment: I think its safe to call this a duplicate

Comment: This is probably the one scenario where I don't think anyone could blame you for not being able to find that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been implemented.

Comment: This is a huge improvement. Yay!