# StackExchange popup closes when using middle click

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

[I recently suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-header-thingy-usability-question/65877#65877) having clicking outside of the StackExchange popup close the window, and it got implmented and works great... most of the time. An unintentional side effect is that now when using middle click to open the topic in a new window, the popup closes.

I'm not able to test this, so is a middle click considered a "lose focus" event? I never did consider it one, but I don't know whats going on.

Tested under Firefox 3.6.10 on Windows XP

Comment: I'll try to fix it; I don't middle click, so I never tested this case.

Comment: @Jarrod: Right-click seems to behave similarly, is that unintentional too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with how the jQuery event object stops event bubbling.  It worked with left clicks, but the other buttons still propagated up and caused the popup to be hidden.

A fix will be deployed this evening.

Answer (score -2):

Middle click is also considered a "click", like left click. That's the intension.

Comment: And on what are you basing this on? What you're describing is incorrect: middle clicking to scroll, for instance, does not trigger this behavior.

Comment: @Chang "middle clicking to scroll" is called the **universal scrolling**; it is not to be mixed up with middle clicking.