# Global inbox disappears on right-click in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackExchange popup closes when using middle click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66108/stackexchange-popup-closes-when-using-middle-click)

If you right-click anywhere on the global inbox, it disappears. Seems to happen only on Firefox (could not reproduce in Chrome or IE).