# The 'X' to close the vote-to-close box is in the wrong place

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

It should be to the top right - like it is in all the other websites and programs - and where people expect it to be.

---

[image]

Comment: Also, it's probably too big for such an uncommon action. And, isn't "cancel" completely redundant now?

Comment: I am guessing it is on the left because all the close options and cancel button are on the left?

Comment: @Barry: so? Notepad's close button is to the top right even if the menu entries are on the left.

Comment: @Kop - I'm not disagreeing with this at all. Just an observation from my point of view.  I agree that the Cancel button should probably be removed too.

Comment: @Barry: Sorry I assumed you were the one who downvoted =p

Comment: @Kop - Not guilty... this time! I up voted :)

Comment: Aha, you're not a Mac. ;-)

Comment: @Barry, not [all close links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-header-thingy-usability-question) ;-)

Comment: @arjan - wouldn't be hard to detect the platform and put in the right place would it?

Comment: @Kop - `Also, it's probably too big for such an uncommon action` --> [Apparently Not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74244/button-to-dismiss-vote-to-close-it-too-big)

Comment: @Barry you mean [like Quora](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora/44641#44641) ?

Comment: @Sathya - WOW! that is some settings page - sometimes you just gotta wonder.

Comment: Dupe of chat: ["window management buttons for OSX are on the left"](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/wild-speculation-about-giant-x)

Answer (score 5):

Given the huge size of these boxes, I like its current place, as it's closer to the link that opens it. Hence, when erroneously clicking that, it's easier to undo that. (Esc seems to work too, though.)

Comment: Wouldn't the best place be the BOTTOM left then? When I click close, the mouse pointer will then be at the bottom left corner.

Comment: In my browser, it depends on the scroll position, @Kop. (Maybe closing on clicking outside the box might be best!)

Comment: Yes, it would be indeed.