# The new inbox is telling me to set my name instead of putting my name forward

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, global-inbox, top-bar

My “Recent inbox messages” on MSO (i.e. with the [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta)) includes the following item, dated 2013-11-25 20:41:53Z:

> Welcome to Web Applications! Visit your user page to set your name and email.

This is a strange message — why tell me that when I've been using the site for a while (like many other Stack Exchange sites)? I presume it should be what appeared around that time in the “notifications” tap of the soon-ex-and-regretted [multicollider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-header-thingy-usability-question):

> The Web Applications Stack Exchange 2013 community moderator election is underway — nominations now being accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't realize that both the welcome code and the election code used the same message type - WHO WOULD HAVE THOUGHT IT!?

This should be fixed now and the offending message type overloads will be sorted out in an upcoming refactor.

Comment: "Welcome to the site...come claim your diamond!"